# How to allow // comments in scss within Stylelint (Unknown Word)

Tags: css, sass, stylelint

I'm new to Stylelint. I tried to understand docs and searched GitHub, but all explanations are full of double negatives and I'm confused!
The problem is that when I use `//` for comments, it throws `Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)Stylelint(CssSyntaxError)`.

#### Examples:

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this issue, or perhaps disable Stylelint check on commented lines?

Comment: Yes, `/*` works correctly but I want to use `//`.

Answer (score 9):

Stylelint is designed for CSS - the language has come a long way in the last few years and extensions like SCSS and Less are often not needed.

However, Stylelint [can](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started/#linting-everything-else) - through community custom syntaxes and plugins - be extended to support SCSS. The easiest way to do this is by extending the [`stylelint-config-standard-scss` shared config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-standard-scss). This config, created by the SCSS community, includes the [postcss-scss syntax](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss) and [stylelint-scss plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-scss) - a collection of rules specific to SCSS - and configures Stylelint's [built-in rules](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list) for SCSS.

You should first install the config as a dependency:

```
npm i --save-dev stylelint-config-standard-scss
```

And then set your configuration object (e.g. your `.stylelintrc.json` file) to:

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-standard-scss"
}
```

---

> The problem is that when I use // for comments, it throws Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)Stylelint(CssSyntaxError).

Double slash comments (`//`) are not standard CSS and can't be parsed by the CSS parser built into Stylelint, hence the syntax error. The SCSS parser included in the `stylelint-config-standard-scss` shared config can parser double slash comments correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I removed this extension called "stylelint-plus" from vs code and this solved my issue.